# C++ concept to inline lambda parameter

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm am trying to pass a lambda (that captures local context by reference) to a function and ensure it is inlined.
I think a solution would be to use a function template and a C++20 concept, but I don't know how to write the concept of a lambda that takes specific types.

The aim is to factorize a complex loops on raster files, and let the caller execute code for each pixel.
**The lambda call must be inlined.**

I had bad luck with:

- `std::function`: the performance with lambda is 2x worse than writing the whole loop in the caller code.
- function pointer: lambda with capture (this or local variable) cannot be casted to function pointer
- template method: I cannot overload it, and cannot check the lambda type as easily as with previous solutions.

Working code with bad performance:

```
// loop
template<typename T>
class Raster<T>
{
    template<typename FileDataType>
    void SaveToDisk(std::ostream& file, const std::function<FileDataType(T&)>& callback) const;
    template<typename FileDataType>
    void SaveToDisk(std::ostream& file, AnotherCallbackType...);
}

// call
class GeoRaster<double> : public Raster
{
    void Test()
    {
        // Creates a file containing "short" values, from a GeoRaster<double>
        SaveToDisk<short>(file, [&](double val)
        {
           // this lambda call must be inlined
           if (val == this->nodata)
           {
               return 255;
           }
           else
           {
              return short(val) / 16;
           }
        }
     }
});
```

Could you help me to write a concept like this:

```
template<typename T, typename FileDataType>
concept SimpleWriteCallback = requires(T a) {
    { a } -> std::convertible_to<std::function<FileDataType(T&)>>;
};

template<typename FileDataType, SimpleWriteCallback<FileDataType> Callback>
void SaveToDisk(std::ostream& file, Callback& callback) const;
```

Comment: __Why__ `std::function`? You require something which is callable with the given arguments, not a `std::function`.

Comment: "*ensure it is inlined*" Why do you care? Why is it your business whether the function is declared `inline` or not? Also, there's no way to ensure *anything* is "inlined", at least as far as the C++ standard is concerned.

Comment: Forcing inlining will require compiler-specific methods to do so, since this is not something officially covered by the standard. For MSVC you can use (IIRC) the `[[msvc::forceinline]]` attribute on lambdas (since `__forceinline` does not work)  in newer compiler versions. For GCC/Clang, `__attribute__((always_inline))` works on lambdas IIRC but `[[gnu::always_inline]]` does not

Comment: I just need it to be very performant. The question could be rephrased as: can I separate loop and single  iteration logic and keep the same level of performance? If so: how? I need the loop to be properly optimized, but since I have a many times the same kind of code in the program I would like to factorize it.

Comment: @Tkausl With std::function, I can express things like: T1 fn(T1, T2). That way I can avoid bugs and typos. If the callback doesn't have exactly the corresponding parameters it is rejected at compile time

Comment: [`function_view`](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html) might interest you.

Comment: @Jarod42 `function_view` seems to be a great alternative to `std::function` and `function pointers`. It seems excellent to describe the callback interface and keep method overloading working. From the comments [LLVM function_ref](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h#L98) provide the same feature.
So there seem to be 2 alternatives that support capturing lambdas: `function_view` and `templates` (2nd one leading to more optimized code)

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are looking for is [std::invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable), which is a concept that allows you to enforce that a type can be called with a given set of arguments:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>

void do_stuff(std::invocable<int, int> auto &&fn) {
        fn(3, 4);
}

int main() {
        do_stuff([](const int a, const int b) { std::printf("%d %d\n", a, b); });
        // do_stuff([] { std::puts("hi!"); }); // won't compile

        return 0;
}
```

If you need to also constrain the return type of `Func`, you may use a `requires()` block to add a *compound requirement*:

```
template <typename Func>
        requires requires(Func &&fn, std::vector<int> v) {
                std::invocable<Func, const std::vector<int>&, bool>;
                { fn(v, false) } -> std::convertible_to<int>;
        }
int do_stuff(std::vector<int> v, Func &&fn) {
        v.push_back(31);

        return fn(v, true);
}

int main() {
    do_stuff({1, 2 ,3}, [](const auto &, bool) { return 3; }); // ok: right parameters, and return type is convertible to int
    do_stuff({1, 2 ,3}, [](const auto &, bool) { return 3.f; }); // ok: float is also implicitly convertible to int
    //do_stuff({1, 2 ,3}, [](const auto &v) { return 3; }); // won't compile, cannot be invoked with (const vector<int>&, bool)
    //do_stuff({1, 2 ,3}, [](const auto &v, bool) { return ""; }); // won't compile, const char (&)[] is not convertible to int
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this: ```void WriteDataFile(std::ostream& file, std::invocable<T> auto&& callback) const
   {
      using FileDataType = decltype(callback(T()));
   }```
I compiles fine with g++10. I still don't get the same level of performance as with hand written loop. (hand written : 1.25s, concept : 1.4s, std::function: 2.5s)  

I forgot I can specify return type of callbacks with `->`

Comment: This syntax also works if I want the caller to specify a template argument : 
   ```template<typename FileDataType>
   bool LoadDataFromFile(const std::string& filePath, std::invocable<FileDataType, T&> auto&& callback)```

Comment: After a lot of tests with this syntax & g++10, my conclusion is that performance is always better without callback.
I did the same tests with a simple template argument without concepts, and the conclusion is the same.
I guess I'm gonna duplicate the logic everywhere -_-

Comment: @Kiruahxh What optimization level are you using? Have you also tried testing with Clang/LLVM or GCC 11?

Comment: `O2` or `O3`, `unroll-loops` and optionnaly `flto`. I didn't know g++11 have been release, I could give a try. The program might be compiled with MSVC later.
Speed may also be important in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

First, we have to start with how we're even thinking about the constraint:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename FileDataType>
concept SimpleWriteCallback = /* ... */;
```

We're not constraining the callback on a `FileDataType`, `FileDataType` is what the callback *returns*. Rather, we're constraining it on the type that we're passing into it:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename T>
concept SimpleWriteCallback = std::invocable<F&, T&>;
```

And you'd then use this concept like:

```cpp
template <SimpleWriteCallback<T> F>
void SaveToDisk(std::ostream& file, F&& callback) const {
    using FileDataType = std::invoke_result_t<F&, T&>;
    // ...
}
```

Now, separately, if you want to override the actual return type (as you seem to do, since the lambda returns an `int` but you want a `short`), you can provide an overload that lets you provide the type explicitly and have the other overload just forward to it:

```cpp
template <typename FileDataType, SimpleWriteCallback<T> F>
    requires std::convertible_to<std::invoke_result_t<F&, T&>, FileDataType>
void SaveToDisk(std::ostream& file, F&& callback) const {
    // ...
}

template <SimpleWriteCallback<T> F>
void SaveToDisk(std::ostream& file, F&& callback) const {
    // by default, FileDataType is the actual invocation result
    SaveToDisk<std::invoke_result_t<F&, T&>>(file, callback);
}
```